PS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse Driver Issue: Touchpad Connectivity Problem
I have Zorin OS 17 Lite installed, based on Ubuntu 22.04, on my PC. My issue is with the touchpad, which is configured with the 'PS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse' driver. When I power on the PC, the touchpad isn't detected for a few seconds and then it starts scrolling upwards automatically. When I check the mouse settings, I see that the driver name appears and disappears every second, indicating that it's disconnecting and reconnecting repeatedly. The temporary solution I've found is to disable and re-enable the mouse in the settings as soon as I start the PC, which temporarily stops the issue, but this is tedious and not a permanent fix. After doing this, the touchpad works correctly for a while, but the problem resurfaces.
Here's a video demonstrating the issue more clearly.video on drive

Because ZorinOS is not an official Ubuntu flavor, this question is off topic here at AskUbuntu but your question is on topic at https://unix.stackexchange.com

Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Zorin forum.  (One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Zorin so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux found in the on-topic link)
